# Disintegration associative

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Is the disintegration of two borelian probabilities measures is associative ? It means if $\mu = \mu_{y}^{1} \oplus h_{\#}^{1}\mu$ and $ h_{\#}^{1}\mu = \mu_{y}^{2} \oplus  h_{\#}^{2} h_{\#}^{1}\mu$. Then do we have
$$
\mu = \mu_{y}^{1} \oplus \mu_{y}^{2} \oplus (h^{2} \circ h^{1})_{\#} \mu
$$
Where $\mu$ is a borelian probability over $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and I note $\mu = \mu_{y} \oplus h_{\#}\mu$ the disintegration of $\mu$ according to $h_{\#} \mu$ that gives the kernel $\mu_{y}$ with $y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

EDIT : To be clearer, we have $\mu = \mu^{1,2} \oplus(h^{2} \circ h^{1})_{\#} \mu$. The question is 
$$
\mu^{1,2}_{y}(A) =? \int \mu_{x}^{1}(A) d\mu_{y}^{2}(x)
$$

Comment: I have problems with your notation. What is $h_2 \circ h_1$? I think if you formulate (if possible) your question with stochastic kernels the answer is simply true. Have a look f.i. in the old book of Bertsekas/Shreve (1978), Stochastic Optimal Control: The discrete Time Case, in particular ch. 7.4.3 Stochastic Kernels.

Comment: I edit thank you. Here the things is we have to check if
$$
\mu_{y}^{1}\oplus \mu_{y}^{2} (\mathbb{R}^{n} - (h^{2}\circ h^{1})^{-1}(\{y\}))=0
$$
And 
$$
y \rightarrow \mu_{x}^{1} \oplus \mu_{y}^{2}
$$
Is measurable.

Comment: Obious edit : 
$$
y \rightarrow \mu_{x}^{1} \oplus \mu_{y}^{2} (A)
$$
Is measurable for any borel set $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Disintegration is associative, in the following sense: Suppose that we have a disintegration 
$$\mu(dx)=\int_Y(\mu h_1^{-1})(dy)\mu_{h_1}(y,dx)$$
of a probability measure $\mu$ with a kernel $\mu_{h_1}$ -- meaning that $\int_X\mu(dx)f(x)=\int_Y(\mu h_1^{-1})(dy)\int_X\mu_{h_1}(y,dx)f(x)$ for all nonnegative measurable functions $f$ on $X$, and that we further have a disintegration 
$$(\mu h_1^{-1})(dy)=\int_Z(\mu h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1})(dz)(\mu h_1^{-1})_{h_2}(z,dy) \\ =\int_Z(\mu(h_2\circ h_1)^{-1})(dz)(\mu h_1^{-1})_{h_2}(z,dy)$$
of the measure $\mu h_1^{-1}$. 
Then we have the disintegration
$$\mu(dx) 
=\int_Z(\mu(h_2\circ h_1)^{-1})(dz)(\mu_{h_1}*(\mu h_1^{-1})_{h_2})(z,dx),$$
where
$$(\mu_{h_1}*(\mu h_1^{-1})_{h_2})(z,dx):=\int_Y (\mu h_1^{-1})_{h_2}(z,dy)\; \mu_{h_1}(y,dx).$$

Comment: We have $\mu = \mu^{1,2} \oplus(h^{2} \circ h^{1})_{\#} \mu$. The question is 
$$
\mu^{1,2}_{y}(A) =? \int \mu_{x}^{1}(A) d\mu_{y}^{2}(x)
$$

Comment: @CechMS : I think you never said what you mean by $\oplus$, $\mu_x^1$, $\mu^{1,2}$, ... .

Comment: The identity $\mu = \mu_{y} \oplus h_{\#}\mu$ means that $\{ \mu_{y}  ; y \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \}$ is a probability kernel such that : 
$$
\mu(A) = \int \mu_{y} (A) d h_{\#} \mu
$$
And 
$$
\mu_{y}(\mathbb{R}^{n} - h^{-1}(\{ y\}) = 0 
$$
We write $\mu = \mu_{y} \oplus \nu$ everytime you have $\nu = h_{\#} \mu$ otherwise even over $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ it could not exist.

Comment: It is still unknown what you mean by $\mu_x^1$, $\mu^{1,2}$, ... . Also, the first displayed formula in your latest comment, with just one entry of $y$, is apparently written not the way it should be.